# Resource on characterizations or properties of traceable graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I am looking for some resources that provide information on traceable graphs(paths containing a hamiltonian path). I have found a lot of information on hamiltonian graphs, but none on traceable graphs.

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards.

Comment: A good (general) requirement for a graph to be traceable would be especially appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to point out that a [*traceable graph*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TraceableGraph.html) is one with a Hamiltonian path
(or, if the OP is not using standard terminology, a clarification would be welcomed).

The [Petersen graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph#Hamiltonian_paths_and_cycles) has a
Hamiltonian path but not a Hamiltonian cycle:

---

[image: PetersenGraph]

 
 
 
 
 
<sup>([Wikipedia image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph#Hamiltonian_paths_and_cycles))</sup>

---

Comment: Oh yes, that is what I meant with traceable graph, I am interested in learning more about them. But resources seem to be scarce. Do you know any characterizations for them? or a place where I can learn about them.

Comment: Because determining if a graph has a Hamiltonian path is NP-complete, it is unlikely there is a clean characterization. Of course there are many theorems that such-and-such a structure implies the graph is Hamiltonian. E.g., every 4-connected planar graph is Hamiltonian.